# Proving asymptotic bounds

Tags: asymptotics

I'm confused if the following approach is mathematically correct

Suppose I have to prove $(\log n)! > n^a$, where $a$ is a constant

I can assume $n = 2^k$
which leads to $k! > c^k$, where $c = 2^a$

The conclusion is true since factorials have a higher rate of growth than exponentials.

My doubt is, is it correct to terminate the proof there and conclude $(\log n)! > n^a$, or should I extend the proof until I get a correct result in terms of $n$?

Comment: That would be fine, if you have proved beforehand that $k!$ grows faster than $c^k$ for any $c$.